# Spark Error when running python script on databricks

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks

I have the following basic script that works fine using pycharm on my machine.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

print("START")

spark = SparkSession \
    .Builder() \
    .appName("myapp") \
    .master('local[*, 4]') \
    .getOrCreate()

print(spark)

data = [('James', '', 'Smith', '1991-04-01', 'M', 3000),
        ('Michael', 'Rose', '', '2000-05-19', 'M', 4000),
        ('Robert', '', 'Williams', '1978-09-05', 'M', 4000),
        ('Maria', 'Anne', 'Jones', '1967-12-01', 'F', 4000),
        ('Jen', 'Mary', 'Brown', '1980-02-17', 'F', -1)
        ]

columns = ["firstname", "middlename", "lastname", "dob", "gender", "salary"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema=columns)
print(df)
```

However when trying to run on a databricks cluster, directly through python script it gives an error.

> START Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
> return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
> exec(code, run_globals)   File "/Workspace/Repos/***********/sdk_test/tests/snippets/spark_tests.py",
> line 13, in 
> class SparkTests:   File "/Workspace/Repos/*******/sdk_test/tests/snippets/spark_tests.py",
> line 16, in SparkTests
> sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()   File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/context.py", line 400, in
> getOrCreate
> SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())   File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/context.py", line 147, in **init**
> self._do_init(master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer,   File
> "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/context.py", line 192, in _do_init
> raise RuntimeError("A master URL must be set in your configuration") RuntimeError: A master URL must be set in your
> configuration CalledProcessError: Command 'b'cd
> ../\n\n/databricks/python3/bin/python -m tests.snippets.spark_tests\n#
> python -m tests.runner --env=qa --runtime_env=databricks --upload=True
> --package=sdk\n'' returned non-zero exit status 1.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `.master('local[*, 4]') \` from your code. Master is set automatically on Databricks.

Comment: still gives the same error :\ I"m running through python file not directly from notebook

Comment: Show how do you trigger the job

Comment: %%sh
cd ../
/databricks/python3/bin/python tests/snippets/spark_tests.py

Comment: it's not the best way of running tests, etc. Look onto dbx instead: https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/dbx.html

Answer (score 0):

Your code works absolutely fine in Databricks:

[image: Output Image]

I will suggest you to restart your databricks cluster and run it again. And check command line arguments for running script.

Comment: Thanks for reply, through a notebook it works fine, but if I run it through the python shell (or trigger the script through a job) it throws this error